# How to Study Effect of zram on Memory Size and Paging?

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, memory, virtual-memory

Situation: to study the effect of `zram`'s virtual memory compression ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zram)) on memory's size and its speed; when swap is not on HDD/SSD; use `zswap` if you want to have swap on HDD/SSD
Motivation: I experience no effect on the memory's size but increased amount of errors from `systemd`/... with `runit` i.e. possible stability issues with the compression, although paging should be avoided more
Code

```
# http://askubuntu.com/a/800645/25388
modprobe zram
echo lz4 > /sys/block/zram0/comp_algorithm
echo 4G > /sys/block/zram0/disksize
mkswap --label zram0 /dev/zram0
swapon --priority 100 /dev/zram0
```

Characteristics

- Command `cat /sys/block/zram0/orig_data_size` gives `4096`.
- RAM full and swap full. So computation ends when total memory consumption reaches the high about 20 GB, failing the computation.

  [image]
- Command `swapon`  baed on `cat /proc/swaps`

  ```
  NAME       TYPE      SIZE USED PRIO
  /dev/sda3  partition   8G   0B   -1
  /dev/zram0 partition   4G   0B  100
  ```
- Command `free -m`

  ```
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
  Mem:         7925         1390        5465      172     1069         6074
  Swap:        12226        0           12226
  ```
- Command `df -k | grep sda2` about current memory use in SSD, possibility to extend it for Swap.

  ```
  Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used      Available Use% Mounted on
  /dev/sda2      108299224     76880916  25893932  75%  /
  % df -h
  /dev/sda2      104G          74G       25G       75%  /
  ```

Test code: any memory-heavy Matlab computation.

Output: the size of matrix does not increase with the implementation. 
Expected output: increase in memory size.

System: Linux Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit
Hardware: Macbook Air 2013-mid

Comment: some useful things to know about swap and about zram:  1. anything swapped out stays swapped out in swap until it's needed again (or discarded, e.g. the program exits). 2. zram uses memory, so when used as swap it effectively gives you transparently compressed & decompressed RAM that's only a little slower to access than normal RAM (but a LOT faster than SSD or HDD swap), but see point 1 (swapped stuff stays swapped).  BTW, disk storage has nothing to do with memory or RAM so the df output is irrelevant...showing `free -m` would be more useful.

Comment: also btw, unless you *like* to divide by 1048576 every time, `swapon` without the `-s` option gives more useful output.

Comment: btw, a quick google tells me that the Macbook Air has soldered-on RAM so can't be upgraded (it could come with a maximum of 8GB which had to be chosen at purchase time).  If you really need to run large matlab jobs, I suggest running them on a remote machine that has 16 or 32GB RAM or more.  Perhaps you have access to a cluster or other large machine via ssh.  if not, build yourself a linux box with as much RAM as you  can stuff into it (32 or 64GB or more).  16GB DDR4 sticks are around $100 each these days and most DDR4-capable motherboards can take up to four of them.

Comment: for older DDR3 motherboards, 8GB sticks are more readily available than 16GB but still cost around $100 per 16GB....but most m/bs are still limited to 4 DIMMs, so a max of 32GB rather than 64GB.  prices are approximate, in AUD, and current at time of writing.

Comment: you set the swap priority when you run `swapon` (or in /etc/fstab).  AFAIK, to change the priority of a swap device you have to run `swapoff` on it first, and then `swapon` again with the new priority.

Comment: Yes. Do you know about `zram` and its effect on the size of total RAM size? I need to compute with big matrices.

Comment: as for increasing RAM with zram....that's a tricky question.  It does effectively increase available RAM (like any swap space does) but it does so by using some of your RAM.  Depending on the type of data you're swapping, you might get 10% or 50% or even better compression (e.g. over 90% on plain text or similar).  or you may get no compression for some data.  and, as previously mentioned, stuff that gets swapped out stays in swap until the kernel has a reason to swap it back in again.  Overall, if you're using even moderately compressible data you're better off with zram than without it.

Comment: zram is not magic.  it can help, but it still won't let you run a job that needs, e.g., 32GB of RAM on a system with only 8GB RAM + another 8GB of SSD or HDD swap.

Comment: @cas I have 30 GB free space still in my SSD. I am trying to turn some of it to swap here http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/297767/16920 So probably, we can get 8 GB RAM + 20 GB of SSD swap.

Comment: you probably want to use zswap.  This works like zram but can also use an SSD or HDD.  see http://askubuntu.com/questions/471912/zram-vs-zswap-vs-zcache-ultimate-guide-when-to-use-which-one

Comment: Finally, swapping is something to be avoided if at all possible.  if you can upgrade your system's RAM, then do so.  If you can offload the RAM-hungry task to another machine, then do so.  Swap is always a last resort, because it's slow.  If you need to run large matlab etc jobs frequently then no amount of swap space will relieve the frustration and tedium of waiting for it to finish (or make your machine interactively usable while it's thrashing data in and out of swap)...which is why i suggested building a linux box you can connect to via ssh to run large memory-hungry jobs on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stop optimising swap memory as instructed by *cas*, focused on other things. Please, note cas' comment

> Finally, swapping is something to be avoided if at all possible. if you can upgrade your system's RAM, then do so. If you can offload the RAM-hungry task to another machine, then do so. Swap is always a last resort, because it's slow. If you need to run large matlab etc jobs frequently then no amount of swap space will relieve the frustration and tedium of waiting for it to finish (or make your machine interactively usable while it's thrashing data in and out of swap)...which is why i suggested building a linux box you can connect to via ssh to run large memory-hungry jobs on.