# How can I increase my virtual memory

Tags: centos, virtual-machine, swap, virtual-memory, openvz

I am starting this question despite it seems like [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/297767/how-to-allocate-more-space-to-swap-and-increase-its-size-greater-than-ram) question, but it isn't.
I am getting different outputs from the commands as given in that question.

Now I want to show you my scenario. [image]

From my knowledge of operating systems, virtual memory is used to swap the files from main memory which are not used frequently and free up space for other active programs and files. My `MySQL Database Server` is getting killed by own, and I don't know why, and I think this is because of the `Virtual Memory`.

So, I want to increase my Virtual Memory.

I read from [this](https://www.vembu.com/blog/increase-swap-memory-centos-7/) link, but again the outputs are a bit different like I don't have some like `sda1` or something. I don't have any knowledge of `Linux` so please explain in more basic terms. I don't know any command neither know what a command does.

Here some of the outputs of the commands.

```
swapon -s
Filename    Type         Size     Used     Priority
/dev/null   partition    524288   516556   -1
```

---

```
free -m
              total   used   free   shared   buffers  cached
Mam:           1024    734    289      128         0      74
-/+ buffers/chahe:     660    363
Swap:          512     504      7
```

---

```
df -h
Filesystem    Size    Used    Avail   Use%    Mounted on
/dev/simfs     40G    3.1G      37G     8%    /
none          256M    4.0K     256M     1%    /dev
```

**So please tell me how can I increase the Virtual Memory size?**

**Edit**

This question marked duplicate but again my terminal giving different output than in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/238783/how-can-i-create-a-swap-file).

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/raid1/swapfile bs-1M count=8192
dd : opening `/raid1/swapfile': No such file or directory
```

I don't have idea what a `mdadm RAID` is.

Comment: `/dev/null` as a swap file sure seems interesting.

Comment: It has become a nightmare for me.  :(

Comment: `/dev/simfs` implies you're running a virtual machine using OpenVZ, which likely means you're paying someone to provide this machine for you.  Your best bet, is to speak to your hosting provider (or check in their support forum if they have one), because OpenVZ containers don't use swap in a traditional sense.  Your actual issue is running out of memory and having MySQL killed, check on here for reducing MySQL's memory requirements, or running low memory configurations.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create a swap file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/238783/how-can-i-create-a-swap-file)

Comment: @TomášPospíšek Commands on the link you mentioned are not working in my scenario.

Comment: If you'd show us the output (i.e. what "not working" exactly is), then of course we could maybe help you.

Comment: I think I posted the output. The image after **Edit**, showing why it is not working.

Comment: Please avoid posting test as pictures. Search engines can't search for such text yet.

Comment: Ok, I will fix it in a minute.

Comment: Screenshots aren't looking very well, use text copy-paste anywhere you can.

Comment: Done @peterh, the question is edited.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm very much mistaken, you can't create (useful) swap on OpenVZ containers, so you should stop trying to extend the existing swap, I'm not even sure you have the necessary permissions to change the existing swap.  It may be defined in OpenVZ, not at the Linux level itself.

It's not real swap, it's fake swap ([vSwap](https://documentation.solusvm.com/display/DOCS/OpenVZ+VSwap)), and it doesn't give you any more memory.

You need to resolve your memory issues by either getting more real memory (paying more for your VM) or by reducing your memory use.

Comment: Well, it will be helpful to me if you includes the ways of **reducing my memory use**.

Comment: +1, as this is also useful, and I need to talk to my provider.

Comment: There are lots of answers on here already about running MySQL with a low memory footprint (I alluded to that in a comment on your question), but if you search and can't find help for that specific issue, I suggest you ask a new question with that as the focus.  Your existing question is _useful_ because others may ask it, so I suggest you don't remove it or change it from it's existing focus, but start a new question (if you need to - search first, there's plenty of stuff on here already about MySQL memory consumption).

Comment: Also, I could be wrong, and someone may come along in a bit and explain exactly how to achieve what you need.

Comment: OK, so I leave this question open, for some other appropriate answers, and then mark the answer in next 2-3 days. Well, Thanks Again.